# wrapping in programming lingo

Tags: terminology, wrapper

Hi could any one explain to me the various ways in which the term "wrapping" is used in programming lingo? I have heard it being used in many contexts esp compilers

Comment: Sure, here's a good example: "I would rather write a program to do my Christmas wrapping"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try and explain the limited knowledge I have here.

Obviously, you have text wrapping, but I take it you're not talking about that.

You can have a `wrapper library`, that is, a library that 'translates' another library's functions into easier to use ones, for example.

As for other wrapper terminology, I'm kinda lost there. Sorry.

James

Comment: Not a bad start. For more info, look into the Facade and Adapter designer patterns, both of which may do some form "wrapping".

Comment: Thanks :) I'm really not experienced enough to comment here, I just wanted to add a little snippet to hopefully help out just a bit :P Thanks for the references too.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner  For me these are the two most prevelant examples.  Maybe decorator to a lesser extent.

Answer (score 2):

**Wrapping** (also called **boxing**) is to put primitive types of a language into an Object, making methods of Object available.

For instance, up to Java 1.5, you would write

Double cash = new Double(1234567.89);

Now, cash is a class Double that provides methods like toString(). With Java 1.5, the compiler makes the wrap (or boxing), and the line above reduces to

Double cash = 1234567.89;